# Hide a Google calendar's events from the notification area

Tags: calendar, notification-area, google-calendar

Under **Settings > Online Accounts**, I'm signed into my Google account.
I have several calendars associated with my Google account, and all their events show in the notification area in Ubuntu. One of the calendars has many events per day, so every day my notification area is filled with its event notifications.

Is there a way to hide the event notifications from just that one calendar, but still display the events from the others?

(In **Online Accounts**, there's a toggle to turn off syncing all the calendars for an account, but that is not granular enough for what I want to do. I am using Ubuntu 20.04, if that's relevant.)